# Firebase Crashlytics NDK unstripped files

Tags: firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics

I have an SDK that uses C++ code. The SDK exports 4 different modules in a maven repo that I publish on either a local maven repo or on GitHub packages.
The apps that consume the SDK should be able to use Firebase Crashlytics and get reports of crashes in the native code as well.

The first problem I have is that I need to provide to the Firebase plugin the folders `unstrippedNativeLibsDir` and `strippedNativeLibsDir`:

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
    nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
    unstrippedNativeLibsDir "???"
    strippedNativeLibsDir "???"
}
```

If I go to the project where I build the SDK I can see: `build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release` and `build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs`.

Are these the unstripped and stripped folder respectively?

Is there any documentation about what exactly those folders are supposed to contain?

Anyway if I configure the app `firebaseCrashlytics` to point to these folders I still need to fix another issue.
I get:

> Crashlytics could not find NDK build tasks on which to depend. You many need to manually enforce task dependencies

It looks like since I'm building the libs that use the NDK in another project, then the Firebase plugin does not work.

What am I supposed to do?
Is it possible to get the Crashlytics NDK working even if I build the libraries independently with a separate project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I made it work was to build the libraries along with the app. The libraries were in separate repos anyway but I included them as sub-repositories in the app.
In this way, you solve the issue of not finding `NDK build tasks on which to depend`.

I know this is not the answer though